# Generate columns where values exist

Tags: sql, group-by, dynamically-generated

I have the following sql:

```
select ks2en, 
   count(case result when 'C-' then 1 end) as 'C-',
   count(case result when 'C' then 1 end) as 'C',
   count(case result when 'C+' then 1 end) as 'C+',
   count(case result when 'B' then 1 end) as 'B',
   count(case result when 'A' then 1 end) as 'A'
from student join subject 
on subject.upn=student.upn 
where name='English'
group by ks2en;
```

Which generates the results below:

```
ks2en   C-  C   C+  B   A
        0   3   0   0   0
2a      0   0   0   0   0
3a      18  0   0   0   0
3b      0   0   0   0   0
3c      0   0   0   0   0
4a      3   11  1   1   0
4b      3   3   36  0   0
4c      1   26  0   0   0
5b      0   3   0   1   0
5c      3   12  4   33  0
```

However, I want to generate the columns so that where a column has no totals ie column A then it shouldn't display.

Comment: That is a display issue and should be handled in your logic.

Comment: Where is this SQL running from?  Within an application you've built?  I would construct the SQL within the application as needed; i.e. I would test for the condition ahead of time and determine if the column should be displayed, and, if so, include that column in your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you might want to follow juergen's suggestion to handle this situation in business layer, but if you insist the logic to be on DB level below is something to ponder.

```
-- just some sample to work with
create table #student (upn int)
  insert into #student select 1 union all select 2

create table #subject (upn int, result varchar(3))
  insert into #subject select 1, 'C-' union all select 1, 'B' union all select 2, 'A'

--first get the Set of unique [result]s
declare @sqlStr varchar(max)

select @sqlStr = '['+ 
replace(
    stuff((select distinct ','+result as [text()]
    from #subject s
        for xml path ('')) ,1,1,'')
        ,',','],[') + ']' 
from #subject s1

select @sqlStr

--assemble dynamic query
declare @sqlStr1 varchar(max)
set @sqlStr1 = 'select *
    from 
(select #subject.*
from #student 
join #subject on #subject.upn=#student.upn) a
pivot (count (result) for result in ('+@sqlStr+')
        ) p'
-- run dynamic query
 exec (@sqlStr1)
```

hope this helps